# Computing an integral with exponent and sqrt

Tags: integration, exponential-function

Can someone help me to evaluate the integral 
$$
\int_{b}^\infty \sqrt{x} e^{-ax}dx. 
$$
I guessed that it has no elementary anti-derivative, and indeed substituting $x=t^2$ and then applying integration by parts resulted in  $\int e^{-at^2}$.

Comment: You can get an answer in terms of the [incomplete gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function).

Comment: @Mhenni I know of the gamma function, but the incomplete one? I'll check it in wikipedia. I'm looking for something `simple'
, if exists.

Comment: It is known that there is no expression for $\int e^{-at^2}dt$ in terms of elementary functions, I believe.

Comment: I already added a link.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Ok I read the article, and it seems that this integral IS the incomplete gamma function $\Gamma(3/2,b)$. Probably I can get nothing more explicit. Thanks!

Comment: Make the change of variables $ y=ax$ to your integral and then compare with the definition of the incomplete gamma function.

Comment: @LiorB-S: I posted the answer.

Comment: I accepted it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\int_{b}^\infty \sqrt{x} e^{-ax}dx= \frac{1}{a^{3/2}}\int_{a b}^\infty y^{1/2} e^{-y}dy = \Gamma(3/2,ab). $$

Answer (score 4):

You can write it in terms of the error function (which is an antiderivative of $\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} {\rm e}^{-x^2}$) as
$$ \frac {\sqrt {b}}{a}{\rm e}^{-ab} - \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2 a^{3/2}} \text{erf}(\sqrt{ab})  + \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2 a^{3/2}}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As you can see in my question, I managed to express it with the erf function.